# How to get the csv output file from google benchmark library and plot it?

Tags: c++, csv, plot, benchmarking, google-benchmark

I am using google benchmark library (https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/docs/user_guide.md) to do time and complexity analysis of analgorithm in C++.

I read that is possible to get an output file in csv or json format and then plot the result. How can I do this?
I tried to follow the istructions on git library read me but it doesn't produce any output file...

My goal is to produce two plots:

1. how grows the execution time in funcion of the input dimension of the array
2. how grows the number of comparison in funcion of the input dimension of the array

I'm using python matplotlib.pyplot library to create the plots and in order to do it I think I need google-benchmark's data in a csv file.

I couldn't find that much documentation or discussion about this library on the web.
Could anyone help me pls?

Comment: In order to prepare the "plot" part, tell us which OS, framework, graphic library, etc. you're planning to use. Solution isn't the same when using Qt and using MFC, or even when using a console application producing a bitmap file...

Comment: @Wisblade question edited